# What parts of T-SQL syntax require mandatory line breaks?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What parts of T-SQL syntax require mandatory line breaks between two commands/queries/etc?

E.g. can I change meaning of a T-SQL script or make it invalid by removing all line breaks?
(except ones in `-- …` comments and `'…'` string literals)

Comment: http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks, I'll take a look, but also T-SQL is more than just SQL-92 I think.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, line breaks can be safely replaced with spaces.  The only exception I know of is the batch separator GO (which is not actually part of T-SQL syntax).

Removing line breaks without replacing them with spaces could lead to lots of obvious syntax errors such as:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTableINNER JOIN MyOtherTable ...
```

Comment: No, replacing wiyh spaces may not be the ultimate solution. e.g. `SELECT * FROM Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2` won't work. You would need a semicolon here.

Comment: Won't also work with `statement --comment`. Tthe next statement would become a comment here if you just replace line break with space.